# Can I get more than two Sky Dragon eyes somewhere?

Tags: pillars-of-eternity

I was thinking about enchanting some stuff to the "Superb" quality once I meet the level requirements, but then I noticed the ingredients that are required for that:

[image]

I know where to get gems, and I have enough of Admeth's Wyrth, but the third ingredient might pose a problem. I killed the one Sky Dragon I know of, and it only had two eyes. As far as I can tell, there aren't any more Sky Dragons around to slay and recycle.

Are there any other sources for Sky Dragon Eyes, or am I effectively limited to enchanting only a single item to the Superb level?

Answer (score 3):

According to [wiki](http://pillarsofeternity.gamepedia.com/Dragon) There are two Sky Dragons in game, adding up to two items enchantable to Superb level. That fits nicely with there being only one Adra Dragon dropping 2 Adra Dragon scales, that allow to enchant, again, two items (of the armor kind).

I don't know of any other source (except cheats of course).

Comment: The wiki is misleading or wrong, I killed one Sky and the Adra dragon and got the achievement for killing all dragons. The two locations are referring to the same sky dragon, there seems to be only one of them

Answer (score 2):

You get two Sky Dragon Eyes for defeating the (single) Sky Dragon in Hylea's Temple.

If you have White Marches Part I, you can get an additional Sky Dragon Eye for defeating Concelhaut. It's on his desk.

---

All together, these three eyes are enough to upgrade three one-handed weapons, or a single two-handed weapon (costing 2 eyes) plus a one-handed weapon.